# Magento price display per store

Tags: magento2, product, price, multistore, scope

I would like to different display product prices for each store. There are 20 to 30 stores on our Magento instance, each store having the same products.  I am looking for something like this example:

```
website1->store1->store view->10 USD
website1->store2->store view->11 USD
```

Comment: check my answer, more precise explained

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one Magento store and want to set one price for store A and a different price for store B. Here is how:

**Step 1.** In the Admin panel, goto System, Configuration, Catalog, then Price.

**Step 2**. Change Price from Global to Website.

**Step 3.** You should see “Website” on the price page for the product now, instead of “Global”.

**Step 4.** For each product you want to set different prices on – select the product, then in the upper left corner you will see the option to chose your store view. Select the first store

**Step 5.** Set the price for the first store and click “Save and Continue Editing”

**Step 6.** Select the store view for your second store and set the price for that store

**Step 7.** Repeat step 6 until all of your store have the prices you want.

Comment: But i need single "website" multi store. Is there any option?

Comment: But i need single "website" multi store. Is there any option?

Comment: yes, it will work ..follow the same steps..change the store and update the price accordingly

Comment: I have tried, but both store having same price only, if i go with multi website it is working.